# React - binding this in constructor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm learning by building a simple test application in which I have a problem with "this" binding. I created this app package yesterday using "create-react-app" so babel and all other plugins should be up to date.

Now about my problem:
If i declare a method in a class using an arrow function to bind "this", then everything works fine

```
class abc extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  someMethod = () => {
    console.log(this);  //"this" works fine
  }
}
```

But when I try to do the same using explicit "this" binding in a constructor, then binding doesn't work and "this" is undefined:

```
class abc extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.someMethod.bind(this)
  }
  someMethod () {
    console.log(this);  //"this" is undefined
  }
}
```

Could you please help me to understand why it doesn't work? I read a few articles and chapters in books about "this" binding in JS and in React and I think that both code samples from above should work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class abc extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.someMethod= this.someMethod.bind(this)  //modified this line
  }
  someMethod () {
    console.log(this); 
  }
}
```

this will work i have make the changes

Answer (score 0):

When you pass [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you don't need to bind this in the constructor. 
the contructor binding is yor "regular" function.You can use these two codes :

```
class abc extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  someMethod =  () =>{
    console.log(this); 
  }
}
```

or

```
class abc extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
 this.someMethod= this.someMethod.bind(this)
  }
  someMethod () {
    console.log(this); 
  }
}
```